# how to set alert for start date and end date depending on the selection?

Tags: javascript

The below code gives alert when start date and end date are blank. Along with this I want something like if start date is filled but end date is not filled it should alert "end date cannot be blank" and vise versa.

```
function validatecommon(cal1,cal2) {
   if ( cal1 == '' || cal2 == '') {
      alert("Start Date and End Date can not be left blank ");
      return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function validatecommon(cal1,cal2) {

 if ( cal1 == '' && cal2 == '') {
            alert("Start Date and End Date can not be left blank ");
            return false;}
else
    if(cal1 && cal1 != '' && cal2 == ''){
     alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
                return false;}
else
    if(cal2 && cal2 != '' && cal1 == ''){
     alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
                return false;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This for the end only:

```
     if(cal1 != '' && cal2 == ''){
           alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
           return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, that as soon as a function 'returns' it stops processing.. ..so only one of these conditions will ever alert.

```
function validatecommon(cal1,cal2) {

    if ( cal1 == '' && cal2 == '') {
        alert("Start Date and End Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;
    }
    if ( cal1 == '' ) {
        alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;
    }
    if ( cal2 == '' ) {
        alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In the first test, the or `||` should be and `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want every single case you can use `else if`

```
 if ( cal1 == '' && cal2 == '') {
        alert("Start Date and End Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;}
 else if ( cal1 == '' && cal2 != '') {
        alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;}
 else if ( cal1 != '' && cal2 == '') {
        alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;}
 else{return true}
```

Comment: No need for the elses

Comment: @mplungjan what you say is true and if you return right away you can also make a switch...

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ( cal1 == '' && cal2 == '') {
        alert("Start Date and End Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;
 }
 else if ( cal1 == '') {
        alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;
 }
 else if ( cal2 == '') {
        alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
        return false;
 }
 else{
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Me too:

```
function validatecommon(cal1,cal2) {
  if ( cal1 == '' && cal2 == '') {
    alert("Start Date and End Date can not be left blank ");
    return false;
  }
  if ( cal1 == '') {
    alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
    return false;
  }
  if ( cal2 == '') {
    alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do so.
The easiest would be use of the else if statement.
If you don't know that I would suggest doing some reading (try W3schools or a tutorial site like codeschool).
Your final code should look something like this:

```
if(!startDate && !endDate) {
    //both are missing, alert here
} else if (!startDate) {
    //only missing start date, alert here
} else if (!endDate) {
    //only missing end Date, alert here 
} else {
  //Both dates present, perform success action
}
```

Note that I've just used !startDate and !endDate here because this way it checks for truthy and falsey values here too. So if !startDate isn't just an empty string but is actually undefined it will enter the appropriate block. Guessing you might not be aware of truthy and falsey since you weren't aware of else if, this is also something I would suggest reading up on. Hope this helps!

Edit: just remembered you're going to have trouble if the variables are the string '0' here, however if you are just checking dates that should be fine, just watch out for that if you use this method elsewhere.